# What file inserts data into core_email_queue table in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, cron, transactional-mail, order-email

I have searched all over internet but found nothing... What file inserts data into core_email_queue table in magento while successfully saving the cart data...

Can anybody help me because I wanted to send email instantly when the user checkouts successfully

Answer (score 1):

Removing the following mail queue code from Template.php , then you will start receiving email when the order is placed by customer or when you click send email from the admin panel "Sales/Orders" tab.

Template.php is located in => **/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php**

```
   if ($this->hasQueue() && $this->getQueue() instanceof Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue) { 

    /** @var $emailQueue Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue */
        $emailQueue = $this->getQueue();
        $emailQueue->setMessageBody($text);
        $emailQueue->setMessageParameters(array(
                'subject'           => $subject,
                'return_path_email' => $returnPathEmail,
                'is_plain'          => $this->isPlain(),
                'from_email'        => $this->getSenderEmail(),
                'from_name'         => $this->getSenderName(),
                'reply_to'          => $this->getMail()->getReplyTo(),
                'return_to'         => $this->getMail()->getReturnPath(),
            ))
            ->addRecipients($emails, $names, Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue::EMAIL_TYPE_TO)
            ->addRecipients($this->_bccEmails, array(), Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue::EMAIL_TYPE_BCC);
        $emailQueue->addMessageToQueue();

        return true;
    }
```

**Dont Edit core override it using core folder , it may break newsletter functionality as they are email queue so do check for it too**

Comment: I am using onepage checkout.. will this work for it?

Comment: Not working... This file doesnt run any time...